# Responsive button with glyphicons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to build an responsive website (small social network), I used glyphicons with buttons and it works fine on full screen,  my problem is that the glyphicons go outside the border of the button whenever the browser width is decreased image included:

[image: glyphicons go outside the button border]

the code is:

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical col-sm-2" style="width: 9% ">
                <br/><br/><br/>
                <button type="button" class ="btn btn-default" style="font-size:3vw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style="vertical-align:middle;text-align: center;"></span></button>
                
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="font-size:3vw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align: center"></span></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="font-size:3vw"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span> </button>
            </div>
```

So my question is: How to make this responsive, whatever is the size of the screen?

Comment: Can you post your code containing glyphicons?

Comment: please post the related code

Comment: Write your code so we can help you

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: @GaryJohnson I inserted the width to solve another problem :)) but now i've removed it, and the problem seems to be solved! I guess this is solution, unless the old problem occur again. Thank You and all others so much

Comment: @ParcRoi Glad I could help. I removed my comment and submitted it as an answer for reference for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the button width set to `style="width: 9%"`. So when the screen is smaller the button width will be `9%` of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bootstrap classes to get your desired output without breaking the icons and buttons. Just use input instead of button and use type = button.

This is a sample code. Hope this helps.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="but1"></label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="but1" value="button" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This will create the button with the icon and you can style them with CSS.